# Can Web 8 support CM databases scaling out with Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: web8

I can see [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A01EA1FD-0819-409F-8F4B-EAB907DC7D87&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A01EA1FD-0819-409F-8F4B-EAB907DC7D87.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A01EA1FD-0819-409F-8F4B-EAB907DC7D87) that with Oracle we can use load balancing across two CM database instances in an active-passive fashion. My question is, is it supported to scale out the Content Manager database (with SQL Server) to be active-active with 2 instances of Content Manager?  For example: in North America there is an instance of the CM and in Asia there is a CM and they share a distributed database.

Answer (score 1):

An active-active setup is not officially supported for Tridion CM MSSQL db. However, you should be able to use SQL Server's AlwaysOn feature

http://stevenpoitras.com/2014/02/configure-sql-db-availability-group/